# Sqlite: How to insert text entered by the user into a sqlite table using Node/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sqlite

I am trying to find out how to pass client (HTML form) data to a Node/Express/sqlite back-end - not sure how to package up the request on the client side and/or extract the request on the server side.

Client code:

```
// listen for the form to be submitted and add a new dream when it is
dreamsForm.onsubmit = function(event) {
  // stop our form submission from refreshing the page
  console.log("SUBMIT clicked!!!");
  event.preventDefault();

  // jeng: save the value to post
  var data = {dream: dreamInput.value}; // jeng: JSON

  const dreamRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  dreamRequest.open('post', '/putDreams', true);
  dreamRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json;charset=UTF-8"); // jeng - after open but before send
  //dreamRequest.send(JSON.stringify(data));
  dreamRequest.send(data);
};
```

Sever code:

```
// jeng: added insert a new row to the Dreams table
app.get("/putDreams", function (request, response) {
  console.log("insertRows called!!");
    var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO Dreams VALUES (?)");
    var val = request.body.dream;
  //var s = JSON.parse("test")
  //request.json();
  console.log("1 "+request);
  console.log("2 "+request.body);
  console.log("3 "+request.body.dream);
    //console.log("4 "+s);

    //stmt.run("test"); // this works!! test is inserted
    stmt.run(val); // this doesn't work - val is undefined - null is inserted
    stmt.finalize();
    response.redirect("/");

});
```

My specific need is to simply take a piece of text entered by the user and insert it into a sqlite table using Node/Express. I've searched everywhere to no avail so far. Any suggestions/pointers would be gratefully appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: The server-side should use `.post` to listen for post method that you are sending from the client.

Comment: Could you include the code itself in the question rather than screenshots of it, please?